# How to achieve 3 vertical divs inside <header>

Tags: css, html, header

Please help! How to achieve 3 vertical div's inside a header tag. 
I defined the header as relative and each inside div's as absolute. 
**For the inside divs**

- div1: set the offset values as top:0 and right:0
  div2: not sure what offset values to set.(please help here!)
  div3: set the offset values as bottom:0 and right:0

enter code here

```
<!--html code -->
<header id="divhead">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="links"></div>
            <div id="social_links"></div>
        <div id="navigation"></div>
</header>

/* css */
#divhead{
    width:960px;
    height:96px;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    background:yellow;
    opacity:.5;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
#logo{
    width:240px;
    height:94px;
    background: url(images/ss_logo_transparent_text.png)no-repeat;/*image width:230.4px/image height:43.2*/
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}
#links{
    width:715px;
    height:22px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:green;
    opacity:.5;
}
#social_links{
    width:715px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background:blue;
    opacity:.5;

}
#navigation{
    width:715px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background:#888;
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to have 3 columns, with each div being its own column?

Comment: Hi Shane, Thanks for the help. I have a header box. In which I want 3 rows(3 divs vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I understood that you might be looking for something like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SsdPH/14/)